# Xperia Z emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

The [Xperia Z](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/phones/xperia-z/specifications/#tabs) has a 1920x1080 screen.

I need to develop an app which specifically targets this device but I currently don't have one.

Thus I'd like to use an emulator with the same specifications but I can't find this screen size in the list of available devices in AVD Manager.

Is it possible to setup a virtual device with this screen size ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just to add to the existing answer there are [Sony Add-ons](https://dl.developer.sonymobile.com/sdk_manager/Sony-Add-on-SDK.xml) available which will also add device definitions for you in AVD:

[image: Sony Xperia Z AVD]

In the Android SDK manager go to **Tools > Manage Add-on Sites….** and add the site
 `https://dl.developer.sonymobile.com/sdk_manager/Sony-Add-on-SDK.xml`
You should get the option to install Sony Device Definitions which will show up in the Android Virtual Device Manager

Comment: BUMP, this answer is outdated

Comment: I've updated the URL: note that it includes newer Xperia Z definitions :/
(Luckily there are Xperia Z definitions still close to the original model)

Comment: Well this is outdated again and I am having a problem finding a proper URL for these.

Comment: did not work for me. Not sure if this is still working for other people.

Comment: @MichaelVescovo Just tested and you're absolutely right: the [device profiles download](http://dl.developer.sony.com/wearables/sdks/Sony_Add-on_SDK/DeviceProfiles.zip) return a forbidden (403) HTTP error status. Not much can be done until Sony remedies this. Shame this doesn't work at the moment. In the meantime, if you know the specifications of your Sony device you can create a new generic AVD with the right specs(screen dimensions/density/RAM/CPU/etc.).

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza ok thanks for confirming. I tried already to reproduce the device with similar specs but it doesn't reproduce the bug I'm troubleshooting that only occurs on this device. I have a real xperia which does exhibit the bug but I was working from home yesterday and it would be nice to not need a physical device as much as possible.

Comment: I know what you mean, but in my experience the real deal is hard to beat. Also, the version of Android you target matters. I&#39;ve gotten bitten in the past by API changes that causes hard to track bugs like silent failures. If you can budget for a spare device it will be worth it, otherwise fingers crossed for friends that like gadgets :)))

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. Open Android Virtual Device Manager, choose Device Definitions tab and Add Device...