# Is there android emulator repo for not commonly use devices?

Tags: android, emulation

I want to test my application test on different emulators than Android Studio provide. Android studio supports mostly Nexus devices. And Genymotion provide some of Samsung,HTC,Sony and Motorola devices. But sometimes I want to test it different devices. Such as Sharp SH-06D or Xperia Z5 which are not provided by Android Studio nor Genymotion. I found some of Sony device repo from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201692/xperia-z-emulator) answer. But it is not updated, newest phone in there is Xperia Z2.

Is there a device repo which I can find the emulator or hardware profile what I want and download it?

Comment: you can always create a custom device by settings the device specifications on android studio.

Comment: I know that but I wonder if there is a repo for that. That will be easier.